# BizTalk WCF_SQL Polling

Tags: biztalk

I have a strange issue with my WCF_SQL receive location polling. The BizTalk server is BizTalk 2010. The polling executes every 1 min and involves executing a Stored_Proc selecting records from a table and updating the selected records status to something like 'Processing'

`Select top 10 * from ProcessingTable where Status = 'New'`

`Update ProcessingTable Set Status = 'Processing' where Status = 'New'`

The receive pipeline is XMLReceive which will debatch the records and route to another orchestration for processing. At the end of the orchestration, there will be a Send port for updating the Status to 'Processed'.

Here comes the issue, during the period when we have our maintenance and the BizTalk DB/Application servers are brought down, host instances will be down and these records will be stuck in 'New' state. After the maintenance and host instances initialized, these records will get picked up immediately and have its status updated to 'Processing'. Strange thing is that it's stuck at this status and never proceed to get updated to 'Processed'. This is only happening for the top 10 records (first pull/pick up). Subsequently, all other remaining 'New' records get picked up and processed successfully. Currently the workaround is to always monitor for those records stuck in 'Processing' and Update these records to 'New' again to retrigger the processing. Anyone has an answer to this problem?

Comment: This very much depends on your specific solution. It seems to me that your send port which updates your status to 'Processed' is not triggered. Can you double check - by means of looking into the tracking - whether or not this send port is triggered? And if so: please check whether it is triggered with the correct parameters.

Comment: Your second sql statement will result in all records outside the top 10 to be set to "processing", which means your polling proc will no longer pick them up on subsequent cycles.

Answer (score -2):

Have you used singleton pattern orchestration for this ? If no then try it once and see if your getting same problem as I suspect it is facing race condition

Comment: -1 Singleton orchestration is a BizTalk anti-pattern

Comment: Yes Tom Singleton is also termed as anti pattern but in this condition I suspect race condition happens while inserting the records

Comment: Apologies for being rash and downvoting your answer. However, you should have explained that in your answer. I'd remove the downvote but it's locked unless you edit your answer

Comment: No problem Tom I like your comment and down voting because it helps me to explain my answer more clearly.